# How to throttle Django error emails

Tags: python, django, error-handling, error-reporting

I use django error reporting via email. It is normally a very helpful feature, except that now we have 5 minutes of database downtime and I got 2000 emails. Is there any middleware that will help me throttle the number of emails django can send out per minute?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using Gattster's great answer as an example, I wrote a simple implementation based on django's built-in cache functions.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
from django.core.cache import cache


class ThrottledAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):

    PERIOD_LENGTH_IN_SECONDS = 10
    MAX_EMAILS_IN_PERIOD = 1
    COUNTER_CACHE_KEY = "email_admins_counter"

    def increment_counter(self):
        try:
            cache.incr(self.COUNTER_CACHE_KEY)
        except ValueError:
            cache.set(self.COUNTER_CACHE_KEY, 1, self.PERIOD_LENGTH_IN_SECONDS)
        return cache.get(self.COUNTER_CACHE_KEY)

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            counter = self.increment_counter()
        except Exception:
            pass
        else:
            if counter > self.MAX_EMAILS_IN_PERIOD:
                return
        super(ThrottledAdminEmailHandler, self).emit(record)
```

And the logging configuration has been changed in Django 1.9 as well, so in order for this handler to work, you need to configure logging as:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'fully.qualified.path.to.handler.ThrottledAdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

where the change is only to change the name of the logger from `django.request` to `django`. If you look in the logging system documentation, this could probably be achieved in a cleaner (?) way by implementing a [logging filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#id5).

Comment: Nice. I like that this doesn't depend on a redis connection and uses django's core cache framework

Comment: `get_cache` is now removed (as of Django 1.9).
using `from django.core.cache import cache` instead -- but there seems to be a problem across multiple threads or processes ... still working on in ...

Comment: Django 1.9 changed default logging configuration so that Django related stuff is logged via `django` logger and **not** `django.request` logger as seen below. Make sure you fix that if you're going to copy/paste the config @Gattster provided.
The logging section should look like:
```
'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            },
        }
```

Comment: @sebhaase feel free to update the answer to reflect the changes in django

Comment: @miha feel free to update the answer to reflect the changes in django

Comment: Looking at the source code of incr, the timeout is reset each time it is called. Which means that once you reach your limit, you have to wait a full PERIOD_LENGTH_IN_SECONDS without any mails before the counter is reset.

Answer (score 8):

I limited emails to 10 per minute by doing the following. This uses a redis connection function unique to my install. I suggest modifying the incr_counter function to suit your needs. To be safe, use a direct redis or memcache connection for this and not any django.cache wrappers.

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'error_email_limiter.handler.MyAdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            },
        }
}
```

error_email_limiter/handlers.py

```
class MyAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    def incr_counter(self):
        c = get_redis_connection()
        key = self._redis_key()
        res = c.incr(key)
        c.expire(key, 300)
        return res

    def _redis_key(self):
        return time.strftime('error_email_limiter:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M',
                             datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            ctr = self.incr_counter()
        except Exception:
            pass
        else:
            if ctr >= 10:
                return
        super(MyAdminEmailHandler, self).emit(record)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to switch to something like [ErrorStack](http://errorstack.com) for error-reporting. I wrote a [django app](http://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-errorstack/) to make it stupid-simple to integrate into your project.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. Did you also evaluate hoptoad.com? I need to decide which service to pick.

Comment: No, I haven't looked at hoptoad in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the database downtime was not intentional, in which case you probably should have put your Django process into some kind of **[maintenance mode](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg82963.html)** or taken it offline?

Otherwise, the usual mail app is [django-mailer](http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/) which might have helped you simply because it stores outgoing mail in your database and thus would have failed :)

If you really need to rate limit it would be best to do so in your MTA.  This could mean the ability to just shut down the part of the MTA process responsible for sending mail or something exotic like using [this patch for qmail to throttle incoming connections as a means of fighting spam](http://spamthrottle.qmail.ca/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe [Nagios' page](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/flapping.html) on flapping is worth reading